# Change text type input to format password

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input text type and I want to change the format when I begin to write something in the input to format password.

This is my html:

```html
<div class="px-0 col-5">
    <label class="px-0 col-12 mdc-text-field">

        <input type="text" class="mdc-text-field__input" style="padding-left: 20px;" name="PWDDossier" id="PWDDossier" value="" />
        <span class="mdc-floating-label" style="padding-left: 20px;">Mot de passe</span>
        <div class="mdc-text-field__bottom-line"></div>
        <i class="material-icons">
                                        visibility
                                    </i>
    </label>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PWDDossier, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Comment: Are you talking about `<input type="password">` ??

Comment: it is a password but i don't want to set the type password i want to set type text to avoid the display of autocomplete browser chrome

Comment: Why not just use `autocomplete="off"` attribute on your input?

Comment: @Cue for this attribute it is not working for this i decided to do another solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This causes the input to be a like a password input (but still text input) when the user enters something into the input.

```js
function make_pw(){
   
   $("#PWDDossier").addClass("pwd");

}
```

```css
.pwd{
    -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="px-0 col-5">
    <label class="px-0 col-12 mdc-text-field">

        <input type="text" class="mdc-text-field__input" style="padding-left: 20px;" name="PWDDossier" id="PWDDossier" value="" onkeydown="make_pw()" />
        <span class="mdc-floating-label" style="padding-left: 20px;">Mot de passe</span>
        <div class="mdc-text-field__bottom-line"></div>
        <i class="material-icons">
                                        visibility
                                    </i>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: edit: the input now stays a text input but looks like password input

Comment: @mecabpazzo95 if you want it cashed as password, the only option is to change the type to password

Comment: problem that this css attribute dosn't work with IE browser just works for google chrome